# jQuery Mobile Home Screen Web App Transition delayed causing flicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, css-transitions, homescreen, iphone-web-app

I have a problem with a mobile website I am building, and after extensive research I cannot find other instances of the same problem.

The problem does not occur when running the app in mobile Safari.  It only is a problem when I save to home screen an run that way.

The problem is as follows:

Using a normal list with links in the form of:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li>
     <a href="example/example.php" data-transition="slide" data-prefetch="true">Example</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I click on the link, the linked page immediately appears for a split second, and then slides into view, so in effect the transition isn't happening until after the page change.

Prefectching the data is a solution I tried, as shown above, but the problem existed before that.  I have tried data-rel="external" or not, and the behavior is the same.  It doesn't matter what transition I use, the result is the same.

```
-webkit-backspace-visibility:hidden
```

hack didn't work, nor did several others that I now cannot remember.
The only solution I have found to the problem - and it is definitely not satisfying - is to set the linked page to have the css

```
#id_of_linked_page {opacity:0;}
```

..and then bind a fadeIn fast function to the $.mobile.pageshow event, and though, it actually looks surprisingly clean given the hackishness of it, it doesn't produce the desired effect, and is not seamless.

Any ideas?

Thanks

p.s.  I am running this with IOS 5.1 on the IPhone 4s (not jailbroken)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are issues with the jQuery Mobile 1.1.1 page transitions (I'm having the same issues). If you disable all page transitions globally, I believe the issue goes away.